# jquery/js error - DOM Error: DOM Exception 8 - When I .html any variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, domexception

I'm receiving a DOM Error: DOM Exception 8 when I try to execute a very simple piece of code. Ive done similar executions a million times and I'm very confused what the problem is.

My Code:

```
$.post('/dataHandlers/return_stats.php', function(data) {
       $('#u').html(data['username']);
       var health = data['health'];
       $('#health_display').html(health);
       $('#energy_display').html(data['energy']);
       $('#money_display').html(data['money']);
       $('#intelligence_display').html(data['intelligence']);
       $('#strength_display').html(data['strength']);
       $('#sidebar').find('#level_display').html(data['level']);
   }, 'json');
```

HTML:

```
<div id='sidebar'>
   <div id ="health_display" class="stats_right"></div>
</div>
```

If I try and .html something that isn't a variable, it works. Whenever I .html any variable whatsoever, I get that error.

Anyone know what this is about? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you `console.log(data)`, is there anything there before you get the error?

Comment: Yes there is, all the data in the array is returned properly. 
I literally can alert(data['health']); right before the .html line and it outputs fine.

Comment: Am I imagining things or is there a missing ) closing brace?

Comment: I stripped down the code for more ease of reading, it's not a syntax error, I have all the closing tags.

I just updated my code for the full function.

Comment: If you notice, I even tried setting the data['health'] as a variable, alerted that variable, which worked. Then .html'd the variable, and still got the error.

Comment: Can you `try{$('#health_display').html(health);}catch(e){console.log(e)}` to see what the error is?

Comment: What does `data.health` contain?  Maybe it's not as valid as you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure you're passing a string to  `html()`; if, for example, those are arrays, you can get DOM errors like that.

ie, `jQuery("a").html([1,2])` throws the same error; you likely have a type problem.

[image]

I wouldn't be surprised if it they're arrays; if you `alert([1,2])`, it just alerts `1,2`, so everything would appear normal.

Comment: I stripped down the code for more ease of reading, it's not a syntax error, I have all the closing tags.

Comment: @Greg Joe is responding to an earlier version of my answer where I mentioned a potential syntax error. I've seen removed it after seeing his edits.

Comment: yahelc you were right on with jquery not viewing the item in the array as a string...The value is a number, but it still should be a string...in any case, if I simply set the variable to += ' '; javascript "converts it" to a string, and then it will output correctly...So I now can fix the problem, although I still don't understand why the problem is occurring to begin with.

Comment: Note that if you have an array of things you want to append, it should work as expected if you do `jQuery("a").html([1,2].join(""))`.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar problem with the output being interpreted strangely by `.html()`.

Did you try using `.text()` and seeing what happened?